# Python: Using .env (dotenv) file with tox

Tags: python, pytest, tox, pydantic

In my Python project, I'm reading environment variables from a `.env` file. I am actually using `pydantic` to read/verify the env vars.

When using `tox`, the `.env` file will be completely ignored. I am wondering how to make `tox` acknowledging the existence of `.env`?

Here's my `tox.ini`

```
[tox]
envlist = py39

[testenv]
deps = -r requirements-dev.txt
commands = pytest {posargs}
```

My `.env` file:

```
ENV_STATE="prod"  # dev or prod
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, I thought maybe `pydantic` loads the content of the `.env` file as environment variables, that is why I wrote this as my first answer:

### original answer

`tox` does some isolation work, so your builds / tests are more reproducible.

This means that e.g. environment variables are filtered out, except you whitelist them.

You probably need to set

```
passenv = YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
```

Also see in the [tox documentation](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-passenv).

### updated answer

This does not seem to be a `tox` issue at all.

I just created a simple project with `pydantic` and `dotenv`, and it works like a charm with `tox`.

#### tox.ini

```
[tox]
envlist = py39
skipsdist = True

[testenv]
deps = pydantic[dotenv]
commands = pytest {posargs}
```

#### .env

```
ENVIRONMENT="production"
```

#### main.py

```
from pydantic import BaseSettings


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    environment: str

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"
        env_file_encoding = "utf-8"
```

#### test_main.py

```
from main import Settings


def test_settings():
    settings = Settings(_env_file=".env")
    assert settings.environment == "production"
```

Comment: The variables in `.env` are not really environment variables, i.e. I can't get them by, let's say, `os.getenv("ENV_STATE")`. So, how can I define them in `tox.ini`? `passenv = ENV_STATE` probably won't do it.

Comment: How do you read the variables from the `.env` file? e.g. in production or in development?

Comment: I'm using `pydantic` `BaseSettings` to read the vars from `.env` (https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/settings/#:~:text=%20Settings%20management%20%201%20Environment%20variable%20names%0A%F0%9F%94%97.,python-dotenv%20or%20pip%20install%20pydantic%20%5Bdotenv%5D.%20More%20).

Comment: Hi Andi, bad news... this does not seem to be a `tox` issue at all. I just created a simple project with pydantic and dotenv, and it works like a charm with `tox`. Here is the repo - you can have a look at it and/or clone it and run it. If your code is public, I can have a look at it, otherwise I have no more ideas why you have problems. If I mistype my env name or anyting else, pydantic throws an error. Can you show us your .env and your Settings class? here is the working code: https://github.com/jugmac00/issue_67734937

Comment: I will update my answer - this has nothing to do with `tox`.